# How can I use specific coordinates with `addresses.get().getAdressLine()`?

Tags: java, android-studio, geocoder

So my app will crash every time I try to get the address info about a specific location (lat and long), but when I assign the `latitude` and `longitude` variables with `location.getLatitude()` / `location.getLongitude()` the app works fine. I don't want the address details from my location, I want them from the specified coordinates (I took my coordinates from google Maps).

The error I get : `Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference`

```
     double latitude = 46.750723170116544;
     double longitude = 23.589887470006943;

     geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
     txt_street_limit.setText(address);
```

Comment: Where is variable declaration of `latitude` and `longitude`?

Comment: Also, when you say "crash", is there an Exception message or something?

Comment: I have lots of lines of code and I forgot to paste de declaration, I edited the question

Comment: I added the error message as well, I don't know why is it null when I put a set of coordinates  I didn't get with `.getLatitude()` / `.getLongitude()`

Comment: Are you sure that the geocoder returns a valid list of addresses? If an exception is thrown the list is just null.

Comment: I tested it like this: I run the app with the `.getLatitude() / .getLongitude()` and I saved the coordinates it displayed. Then I put those coordinates manually inside the `geocoder.getFromLocation()` and it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Desperate times call for desperate measures: you should launch a debugger and look line by line what is going on and why you have a `null` object. And maybe compare with the version that works.